# [XXX retainCount]==0 really represent memory released?

Tags: objective-c, nsmutablearray

all
when i use [nsmutablearray removeAllObjects]
i got :
      [nsmutableArray retainCount]==1;

then,i use [nsmutableArray relese];
i got [nsmutableArray retainCount]==1;

so ,i think ,is [XXX retainCount]==0 really represent memory released???

Answer (score 5):

From [the official docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmObjectOwnership.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000043-BEHDEDDB):

> **Important**: Typically there should be
>   no reason to explicitly ask an object
>   what its retain count is (see
>   [retainCount](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSObject_Protocol/Reference/NSObject.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/NSObject/retainCount)). The result is often
>   misleading, as you may be unaware of
>   what framework objects have retained
>   an object in which you are interested.
>   In debugging memory management issues,
>   you should be concerned only with
>   ensuring that your code adheres to the
>   ownership rules.

Answer (score 3):

retainCount can never return 0.